# Set Cache-Control key metadata

Tags: metadata, cache-control, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am transcoding a file from flv to mp4 using Amazon elastictranscoder but I couldn't find a way to set the Cache-Control key metadata to max-age=3600 through the API when creating the transcoding job

Comment: I solved this by applying a copyObject CacheControl & MetadataDirective settings. But I need to know if there are any other ways other than copying the object all over again?